# What kind of checksum is this function calculating?

Tags: javascript

This is a function where `bytes` comes from a `string`, and each letter's char code was grabbed to create an array of `bytyes`

```
function checksum(bytes) {
    var a = 0;
    var b = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        a = (a + bytes[i]) % 0xff;
        b = (b + a) % 0xff;
    }

    return (b << 8) | a;
}
```

I'm mostly confused at the role of `% 0xff` and `b << 8`. Could someone help me break this down?

Comment: The 0xff is a hexadecimal number and the b << 8 | a is a bitwise operator. Alas I don't have enough experience with these to know what exactly it's doing.

Comment: `% 0xff` same as `% 255` which is the remainder after dividing by 255, 

% is also known as `modulo` - so a will always be 0 to 254

`b << 8` is b left shifted by 8 binary places ... or, b multiplied by 256

as to what sort of checksum this is ... simplistic, almost useless, and inherently flawed especially since it's using % 255, you'd expect % 256

Comment: Any news about this?

Answer (score 1):

a is equal to the sum of all the elements modulo 255
b is equal to the sum of all the values that a assumes modulo 255 (so 1 time the last element + 2 times the one before that ....)

The final value is a 16 bit number where the higher 8 bits are b and the lower 8 bits are a.

That is actually a Fletcher's checksum

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum

Answer (score 0):

This function calculates a and b, and generates the checksum from it.

**a** is calculated as follows:

- 0+the value of the current char
- a must be between 0 and 254, hence modulo 255 is applied

**b** is calculated as the cumulative value of a modulo 255

- increase the value of b by a
- b must be between 0 and 254, hence modulo 255 is applied

at the end the **checksum** is generated by concatenating a to b

- take b's bits and move them 8 places to the left
- set a to the right side of b

The result will have a length of 2 bytes (16 bits), where the first byte is b and the second a.

**Example:**

```
(c is the current char value)
c    | a   |b
----------------
8    |8    |8
13   |21   |29
5    |26   |55
0    |26   |81
180  |206  |287
100  |51   |83
cheksum = 51,83 = 0x3353 = 0011 0011 0101 0011
```